# Insertar datos en tablas diferentes en un mismo formulario

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo dos tablas una es de productos y otra es de imágenes como puedo ingresar datos en un solo formulario?
La verdad no se casi nada de Laravel, les agradecería mucho que me puedan ayudar

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    // INSERT
    $result= new Producto();

    $resultImagen=new Imagen();
    $file = Input::file('foto_img');
    $nombre = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $resultImagen->foto_img = $nombre;
    \Storage::disk('local')->put($nombre, \File::get($file));

    // como puedo guardar estos campos??  como está ahora solo guarda los datos de la tabla productos
    $result->fill($request->all())->save();
    Session::flash('message', config('content.session.create'));
    return redirect()->route('productos.index');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo te falta la instrucción para guardar los datos de la imagen $resultImagen->save().

```
     public function store(Request $request)
{

    $file = Input::file('foto_img');
    $nombre = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    \Storage::disk('local')->put($nombre, \File::get($file));

    // como puedo guardar estos campos??  como está ahora solo guarda los datos de la tabla productos
    // INSERT
    $result= new Producto();
    $result->fill($request->all());
    $result->save();

    // aquí guardas las imagenes
    $resultImagen=new Imagen();
    $resultImagen->idProducto = $result->id;
    $resultImagen->foto_img = $nombre; 
    $resultImagen->save();

    Session::flash('message', config('content.session.create'));
    return redirect()->route('productos.index');
}
```

Comment: Me salió un error como puedo corregirlo, 
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'idProducto' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `imagen` (`foto_img`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (bufandas-2.jpg, 2019-04-28 22:07:07, 2019-04-28 22:07:07)) "

es decir como puedo hacer que el id de producto se llene en el campo idProducto que es la fk de la tabla imagen?? Te agradecería mucho la ayuda

Comment: He editado la respuesta, puedes probar ahora.

Comment: Aun me sale el mismo error, no se en donde estoy enviando mal.
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'idProducto' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `imagen` (`idProducto`, `foto_img`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, bufandas-2.jpg, 2019-04-29 06:54:12, 2019-04-29 06:54:12))
Te agradezco mucha la ayuda ....

Comment: Buenas, he modificado de nuevo la respuesta. Lo pruebas y si falla me puedes enviar que te da dd($result); depués de $result->save();.

Comment: Si me funcionó!! muchas gracias ... :) Víctor otra pregunta ... como puedo mostrar la imagen en el index quiero que me aparesca igual por id es decir que va a estar dentro de un @foreach :)

Comment: Debes crear otra pregunta.